# How do I specify the debug_mail_directory for the devel maillog?

Tags: 8, debugging

In `settings.local.php`, I have set my local dev environment to use the Devel module's mail logging function:

```
 $config['system.mail']['interface']['default'] = 'devel_mail_log'; 
 $config['devel']['settings']['debug_mail_directory'] = "???";
```

The [DevelMailLog](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/src!Plugin!Mail!DevelMailLog.php/8) documentation says that:

> Filename pattern controlled by 'debug_mail_file_format' config setting.

What do I put for the filename pattern?  I have tried several patterns:

- public://devel_mail
- private://emails
- sites/default/files/devel

But none of these work.  I checked watchdog, but apparently devel mail doesn't leave any logs.

NOTE 1: There is a note in the docs that config settings are broken, but the linked issue is already fixed.

NOTE 2: By default, when I enable devel and export the config, the value for `debug_mail_directory` is `temporary://devel-mails`, but I don't want to store them in the temporary directory; I want to store them in the Drupal files directory if possible.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/managing-mail-handling-for-development-or-testing

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
$config['devel.settings']['debug_mail_directory'] = 'private://mydirectory';
$config['devel.settings']['debug_mail_file_format'] = 'mypattern-%to-%subject-%datetime.mail.txt';
```